# Should I be concerned about this VPN logging?

Tags: vpn

I am currently using [BT Guard](http://www.btguard.com). It has no client on my PC, although I connect through OpenVPN.

I pay about 9€/month for BT Guard, who say that they keep no logs.

However, [Tiger VPN](https://www.tigervpn.com/) which also uses OpenVPN says that it logs only time spent connected and amount of data currently has a US $29 lifetime subscription special.

It would seem that I should switch to that, but lack the knowledge to decide.

Please note, I am **not** asking which is better, just what I should be taking into consideration when making my decision.

Comment: You have to use your own risk tolerance to determine which service you will trust more.

Comment: I agree, but what do I base that on? Can you point me at some URLs where I can learn (for dummies ;-) ?

Comment: What's your threat model? For instances; are you worried about MiTM when at a coffee shop, your ISP monitoring every _funny cat_ picture you re-share, or some online retailer correlating WebMD searches for the best ointment to advertise to you, etc... It really depends upon these, and other factors, that I'd suggest narrowing down your options with. Also what sacrifices are you willing to make, I don't mean goats as such, but more of what are you willing to do to achieve your goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are using a VPN to ensure anonymity. As such, any logging raises concern and even this simple logging can be problematic.

For example, let's say that a Tiger VPN user did something that raised the eye of law enforcement. If law enforcement can determine the times of the illicit activity and that Tiger VPN is the source of the illicit traffic, they might be able to subpoena Tiger VPN for a list of all users who were online at the times of the illicit activity.

At this point, it doesn't matter whether you were the perpetrator of the illicit behavior or not. You now have law enforcement examining your activities. This will likely lead to a (big) loss of your anonymity.

I'm sure that there are other ways that online times can be used to violate your anonymity, this is just the example that came to mind. Note that I'm not an attorney and do not know if such a subpoena could be obtained (though I suspect it could be in some situations).

Comment: A very good point. I suppose even time zones might give something .... (as in what was the lcoal time when somethign was logged) best stay where I am then

Comment: Otoh, wouldn''t I have the public router defense? They know it's one of us, but not which? On the other other hand, that might be enough to justify a search of my PC.  Sorry that I can't upvote you, but I don't have 15 rep yet

Comment: @SamFox Once law enforcement starts looking at you there has to be reduced privacy. And don't worry about the upvote. Glad I could help.